# When can we think of a ring as a ring of polynomials over some subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $x\in R$.

When can we think of $R$ as a ring of polynomials $P[x]$ where $P\subset R$ ?

The condition i can think of (intuitively) is: there exists $x$ s.t.$$1)\ n\neq m \in \mathbb{N}\Rightarrow x^n\neq x^m\\2)\ ab=x\Rightarrow a=xb^{-1} \text{ or }b=xa^{-1} $$
and, to make the polynomials of the form $f=\sum_0^na_i x^i$ and not $f=\sum_{-m}^na_i x^i$: $$\nexists y ,yx=1.$$

If this looks right, how can i prove \ generalize it to polynomials with several indeterminates?

Comment: I can't see how your conditions ensure us that every element of $R$ is a polynomial in $x$. Moreover, what is $P$ in this story?

Comment: In addition to what @user26857 pointed out I would be worried about identifying the subring $P$. My first guess was to start with the condition of the existence of a derivation: an additive homomorphism $d:R\to R$ such that $d(r_1r_2)=d(r_1)r_2+r_1d(r_2)$ for all $r_1,r_2\in R$. Then $P$ could be the kernel (it follows that the kernel is a subring). But, this is not enough for there are the obvious problems in characteristic $p$ (and possibly others) :-( Duh, we clearly need $d$ to be non-trivial, and require the existence of an element in $R$, call it $x$, such that $d(x)=1$.

Comment: What is $b^{-1}$ in a ring? Do you mean if $ab=x$ then at least one of $a$, $b$ must be invertible? What do you mean by "polynomial" with negative powers of $x$?

Comment: @mathguy yes, i mean one is invertable. by "polynomial" with negative powers, i mean formal sums with addition for each power by itself, and multiplying by convolution.

Comment: In math it is generally not allowed to redefine a well-established term. Polynomial means one thing: a sum of non-negative, integral powers of the variables. If you want to work with sums with negative powers, you must call them by a different name.